# pd.read_excel parses dates automatically and parses it wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

In `pd.read_excel` pandas automatically parses the **columns names** as date. And parses it wrong. The date is `dd/mm/yy` and it parses it as `mm/dd/yy`.

The column names are date.

## code used

```py
df = pd.read_excel('check.xlsx')
print(df)
```

The df printed has dates parsed in wrong format

Here's the excel file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rgl0Je5EyxpBunk7FWPHcpZxXFdUZUni/edit?usp=drivesdk&ouid=109057655084381529864&rtpof=true&sd=true . The column names are in `dd/mm/Y` format.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Excel dates aren't stored as strings, they're stored in a binary format. Specifically, as a decimal (OA Dates) whose integer part is the days since 1899-12-30 and fractional part the time of day. How are you reading the dates? Does the Excel file really contain dates? Or strings assumed to be dates?

Comment: I don't have Excel, but I downloaded the file and looked at it with Apple's Numbers, and it looks as though the dates in the file *are* m/d/y. For example, the rightmost column has 1/6/16 which, if I change the format to YYYY-MM-DD, displays as 2016-01-06. So until convinced otherwise, I'll call this a mistake in the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'%Y-%m-%d'` for formatting like you wish.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["26-12-2007", "27-12-2007", "28-12-2007"]})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Date
0  2007-12-26
1  2007-12-27
2  2007-12-28
```

You can also set the column labels to equal the values in the first row with e.g.

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
```

Comment: Plss see the edited question.

Comment: idk what's your problem, it work's for me tbh :D 
Maybe try to import them as CSV (pd.read_csv("...")). Oftentimes I got much less trouble with CSV files then with xlsx :)